# Android App, Update without marketplace. App not installed

Tags: android, installation, monodevelop

We develop an app for android. When we installed the app for the first time, the app works. When we do some changes on the source, we can't install the app again without deleting it from the phone.

Is there any known workaround? When we install the app the second time, the phone shows "App not installed".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are having some kind of namespace collision. I get this sometimes when I duplicate a project. You need to preserve a unique mapping of APK signing key to package name. See the [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) blog post for more details about preventing package confusion.